# Paypal P2P payments API

Tags: paypal, p2p

I want to build a webapp where users can pay to another users via their paypal accounts.

What I want is something similar to this:
https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

A page where the users can click a button to either pay with Paypal or credit card, **to another user**.
But I can't see how in this example can I configure the receiver account. Seems that the payment is made to my account, but I want **the payment to be made to another user that he selects**.

I have also looked to all these APIs:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/rest-sdks/#
but am not able to find an example that allows to build a client where an user pays to another user. And of course, I need to get the confirmation that the payment has been done.

EDIT:

I have tried the code here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@paypal/checkout-server-sdk

And updated to add the payee field:

```
exports.pay = function (req, res) {
    // 1. Set up your server to make calls to PayPal

    // 1a. Import the SDK package
    const paypal = require('@paypal/checkout-server-sdk');

    // 1b. Add your client ID and secret
    const PAYPAL_CLIENT = 'xxx';
    const PAYPAL_SECRET = 'yyy';

    // 1c. Set up the SDK client
    const env = new paypal.core.SandboxEnvironment(PAYPAL_CLIENT, PAYPAL_SECRET);
    const client = new paypal.core.PayPalHttpClient(env);

    // 2. Set up your server to receive a call from the client

    // 3. Call PayPal to set up a transaction with payee
    const request = new paypal.orders.OrdersCreateRequest();
    request.requestBody({
        "intent": "CAPTURE",
        "purchase_units": [
            {
                "amount": {
                    "currency_code": "USD",
                    "value": "100.00"
                },
                "payee": {
                    "email_address": "payee@gmail.com"
                }
            }
        ]
    });

    const createOrder = async function () {
        const response = await client.execute(request);
        console.log(`Response: ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
        // If call returns body in response, you can get the deserialized version from the result attribute of the response.
        console.log(`Order: ${JSON.stringify(response.result)}`);
        return res.status(200).json(response.result);
    };
    createOrder();
};
```

This returns a list of 4 links. The second one seems to be the one to redirect the client to (https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=9RM83779YH010823U). But if I go there, I still can't see the payee address (payee@gmail.com) in the "sent to".

[image: Paypal wrong send to]

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to set a `payee` object: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/custom-payee/

Comment: I tried that, but if I add the payee field in the example, it doesn't seem to do anything. The "send to" field in the Paypal modal doesn't show the specified payee

Comment: The field works when used correctly as documented. Incorrect usage is ignored.

Comment: I have updated the question with some code to help reproduce the problem

Comment: It works as it should. I do not know what you are complaining about.

Comment: I am asking how to make payments to another paypal user through my web site. For example I want the user A to make a payment to user B. If the user B paypal account is "payee@gmail.com" I would expect to see "payee@gmail.com" in the "send to" field. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't know what "send to" field you are talking about. If you put your purchase_units payee object in the demo at https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client , the payee will receive the funds.

Comment: I have added an image so that maybe now it is more clear what I am saying. I would expect here to see the receiver account, instead of "test buyer" from "Albacete". This "test buyer" appears no matter the payee address I test with

Comment: That's the shipping address of the payer. It has nothing to do with the payee.

Comment: (Please note that payee and payer are two different words, and two different parties in a transaction)

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't understand. If the payee is the address of the payer, then why does it appear in the "send to" section? who is paying to who in this case? I want the user A (the one that logs after clicking the button) to pay to the user B (payee@gmail.com). Is this happening at all?

Comment: The payee is not the address of the payer. Or if it is, this is incidental.  It may help you to log in with a payer account with a different address, so that you do not get confused.

Comment: I have created two users (personal) in the sandbox, User A (the user that will pay) and user B (the user that will be paid). I put the user B in the payee "email_address" field. When user A clicks the button, he logs to Paypal with his email and sees the email of B in the very top. Seems fine. However once he clicks on "Continue", a "processing" loading appears, and then the login window appears again. If I log in sandbox to these users accounts, the balances have not changed. So, it has not worked. What is missing?

Comment: I do not know. You have not provided any information about the error message from the Dev Tools console, nor have you provided a testable example (which would be best, since this is sandbox). It would have to be something like https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client with the appropriate purchase_units

Comment: I have created the example https://jsfiddle.net/25q1L7ju/ ...and ...it works... The transaction is successfully made from the user A to the user B. The only difference between this fiddle and my local instance is that the payee is not shown at the very top of the paypal confirmation window. I think it should appear somewhere, for the payer to be sure who is he paying to. shouldn't it?

Comment: This "payee" field could be what I have been chasing around for to transfer a payment from A to C. I think A will pay a fee to send, and C will pay a fee to receive ... but what about B who published the button code on their site? (to whom the IPN will send details) Will they pay any fees since they are "out of the loop"? (My idea is an NFT variant: A wants to purchase from C, but the NFT is being advertised by site B. Technically, B isn't making a sale, so doesn't want to have to pay any fees as he's not being paid

Comment: B will not see any fees or account transfers and will not receive IPN notifications unless using old APIs, which they should not be doing. IPN is 20 years old, and does not belong in any current integration. They could receive webhooks if subscribed. In general the capture API response of a server-side integration https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server is more immediate and useful than webhooks, which are not necessary to implement.